# ¿Alguien sabe por que no muestra los productos?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 

require_once 'connection.php';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT pk_articulo, descripcion, marca FROM cat_articulos ORDER BY pk_articulo DESC");

$array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    array_push($array, array(
        'pk_articulo' => $row['pk_articulo'], 
        'descripcion' => $row['descripcion'], 
        'marca' => $row['marca'], ));
}

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Son alrededor de 30 mil productos pero me muestra nada solo una pagina vacia pero al hacer la consulta en mysql si muestra todos

Comment: Has revisado los logs?

Comment: es que no me ningun error solo no me muestra los productos pero si pongo menos si los muestra

Comment: De nuevo, revisa los logs cuando termina en blanco; puedes encontrarte con algo. Asi mismo, trata de atrapar cualquier excepcion con un try catch alrededor

Comment: En el php.ini o bien en tu archivo php tienes definido un límite máximo de memoria? Porque la consulta es muy pesada y eso hace que no se muestre nada en la pantalla.